# Google sheet, function break when more than 10 rows

Tags: google-sheets

I got this Google Sheet that used to work great.
The problem is, tt breaks after 10 rows or something, not sure why.
Col B stops getting values. I guess something limit amount of rows to fetch, but not sure what it is.

The error is related to col A and B.

The data for col A and B comes from FormdataFilter sheet, col G and K.

Link to my sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zmyjso9OYa2kioSkW8EFuf2zDWKqEufsllUYgnR3Q4I/edit?usp=sharing

The data comes from FormdataFilter sheet, that is a based on Formdata.
The data is used for a game, where players can reserve two items.

I use the FormdataFilter to filter old rows (they can submit a form again, to "override" the old reserved items).

Hope one of you will be able to help me on this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the formula in B2 to `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, FormdataFilter!G2:K, 5, 0)))`.

Notice the range was "A2:A10" and it is now "A2:A" to include the whole column and not just 10 results.